# performance SaveOrUpdate objects in nhibernate

Tags: performance, nhibernate

im using NHibernate to communicate with my database and have some performance problems when saving/updating the data.

I have an IList with objects. Reading from the database works well. The first time the application is running, the table in the SqlCompactEdition is empty, and has to be filled. Therefor i call the SaveOrUpdate method. It works great, all data is entered. But... the performance is very bad, i have to wait some minutes for all data has been added to the database. 
Is there a faster way to add the data to the table? (or any good example/reference?)

Comment: A few questions for clarity: What makes you believe NHibernate is the cause? Have you seen the SQL statements it is issuing?

Comment: for every item inserted i see an instert statement (as expected). currently, i dont know who uses the most time, nhibernate, or sqlcecompactedition.

Comment: How much data are you inserting 100,1000,10000, 1000000 records? You sure it is NHibernate? I would bet it is not, otherwise this would be issue with everybody that is using it.

Comment: about 5000 items, it takes more than a minute...

Comment: issue solved, thanks to all. figured out that the session was opened/closed for every SaveOrUpdate... Fixed, and it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

and remember you can even set the batch size in the config file to improve performance batching together INSERTs and UPDATEs:

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">250</property>
```